# error while creating database in altibase hdb : Invalid Database Name

Tags: database, in-memory-database, isql

I'm new to altibase hdb. I was installed altibase hdb with the instructions from here:
http://support.altibase.com/manual/en/631b/html/Installation/index.html

after using the links guides I was able to start the server well but I could not create the database via the recommended command:

CREATE DATABASE mydb INITSIZE=10M NOARCHIVELOG CHARACTER SET KSC5601 NATIONAL CHARACTER SET UTF16;

after some manipulation I found out that the datafiles and anchorlog files were exist here:

$ALTIBASE_HOME\Altibase\altibase-HDB-server-6.3.1\logs

$ALTIBASE_HOME\Altibase\altibase-HDB-server-6.3.1\dbs

So I cleaned them and now I can use the command above to create the database. but if I just rename the databasename to forexample mydbb instead of mydb the command does not work and get me the following error:

Invalid Database Name. Check The Properties and retry.

So what's problem with the database name? what's the difference between mydb and mydbb????

Comment: The problem was just occured on Windows 
When I tried the Altibase HDB on linux there was no problem...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that this same issue should occur even if you install ALTIBASE HDB on Linux.

If you are going to change the database name using the "CREATE DATABASE" command, you must also change the DB_NAME property in your $ALTIBASE_HOME/conf/altibase.properties file to match.

Once you do so, the command you specified should work fine.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But what if I want to haev two databases at the same time in one Altibase HDB instance?what should I do?

Comment: I think some of the confusion is due to different naming conventions by different DBMS providers.  You cannot have multiple "databases" in one Altibase HDB instance, you can however have multiple "schemas" in a single Altibase HDB instance.  The DB_NAME property is the instance name.  If you're thinking of databases in the SQL Server sense, you can simply create different users inside Altibase and they will be treated similarly.  Altibase's paradigms are similar to Oracle's.